# Find files from a folder containing a series of files that are versioned based on filenames

Tags: c#

Given are a directory containing 
  AA20180501_1.txt
 ,AA20180501_3.txt
 ,...
 ,AA20180501_(n).txt
 ,AA20180502_1.txt
 ,...
 ,AA20180502_(n).txt 
and so on.

I need to add the file with the highest (_n) for each day to an arraylist and I need to do it in C#.

Did I mention that my knowledge of C# is sketchy at best? 
Any ideas and suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: This is too broad to answer, and we are not a code writing service. Use google to find out how to search the files in a directory, how to manipulate strings, etc.

Comment: @MongZhu look at the filenames...they are date stamped...hence the "for each day" comment...

Comment: @MongZhu `how are we supposed to know that?`  Asking is usually effective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this simple solution ...

```
        DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Temp\");
        var files = directory.GetFiles("*.txt")
            .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
            .GroupBy(x => x.Name.Substring(2, 8))
            .Select(x => x.Last())
            .ToArray();
```

Comment: This is the better answer. And you could combine this into one statement if you simply remove the `var files =` statement. Also, I would suggest making it .ToArray(), like the OP asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Feel free to change file extension to the one you need

```
string pattern = "(?i)([a-z]+[0-9]+)_([0-9]+).txt";
var his =
    from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\Temp\test\", "*.txt")
    let match = Regex.Match(file, pattern)
    where match.Success
    let info = new { Name = match.Groups[1].Value, Num = match.Groups[2].Value }
    group info by info.Name into g
    select new { FileName = g.Key, MaxNum = g.Max(x => x.Num) };

foreach(var hi in his)
{
    WriteLine($"File name '{hi.FileName}' has max num: '{hi.MaxNum}'");
}
```

Comment: When I output the filename, it's missing the `"_(n)"` pattern before the file extension. The key `match.Groups[1].Value` does not seem to provide the full file name??

Comment: @AussieJoe Beg your pardon, but I didn't understand what you're trying to say. OP showed an example file names very clear.

Comment: When I run your example, my output looks like **AA20180501** instead of **AA20180501_1.txt** I think your key value is incorrect for this answer. It's very close but not correct.

Comment: @AussieJoe Just concatenate strings: `$"{hi.FileName}_{hi.MaxNum}"`

Comment: That's not an arraylist :P

Comment: I am also getting extra results in your output. `his` has an extra entry for "_" in the output list. Why?

Comment: @AussieJoe `var arr = his.Select(hi => $"{hi.FileName}_{hi.MaxNum}").ToArray();`

Comment: @AussieJoe _Why?_ Corrected code. Non-matches are filtered away.