# How to create an index file without adding the files with the same name, if found in multiple folders

Tags: c#

How to create an index file without adding the files with the same name, if found in multiple folders?

The following code searches a directory and gets all of the `pdf`s in it and writes the paths in a `txt` file. My problem is that if the same file is found in two different folders it gets added twice in my index.txt file causing problems when searching the index file.

### Here is my code

```
    public void createIndexedFileWithContentFromDirectory(string indexPDFDocumentName, string sourceDirectory, string fileExtension)
    {
        bool indexFileExists = File.Exists(indexPDFDocumentName);
        if (indexFileExists == false) {

            var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, fileExtension, SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            File.WriteAllLines(indexPDFDocumentName, files.Select(x => System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x) + "=" + x).ToArray());

        }
    }
```

### This is how the index file looks like

> myfile1=C:\Folder1\myfile1.PDF
> myfile2=C:\Folder2\myfile2.PDF
> myfile3=C:\Folder3\myfile3.PDF
> myfile1=C:\Folder4\myfile1.PDF
> ...

Please note that `myFile1` was added twice since it exists in two different folders. What I would like to be able to do is ignore a file if it was already found so the index file contains only the location of the first file found.

### Somethign like this...

> myfile1=C:\Folder1\myfile1.PDF
> myfile2=C:\Folder2\myfile2.PDF
> myfile3=C:\Folder3\myfile3.PDF
> myfile4=C:\Folder4\myfile4.PDF
> ...

What would be the best way to filter and only add the first file found to the index file even if the file exists in multiple directories?

**EDIT:**
Here is my solution, it may not be the most efficient but it works fine.

```
  public void createIndexedFileWithContentFromDirectory(string indexPDFDocumentName, string sourceDirectory, string fileExtension)
    {

        bool indexFileExists = File.Exists(indexPDFDocumentName);
        if (indexFileExists == false) {

            var allFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory, fileExtension, SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            string[] allFilesArray = allFiles.Select(x => System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x) + "=" + x).ToArray();

            /// This dictionary is created from the above array and it's used for filtering duplicates
            var dictionaryFromArray = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dictionaryFromArray = allFilesArray.Select(s => s.Split('=')).GroupBy(a => a[0].ToUpper()).ToDictionary(e => e.Key, v => v.Select(a => a[1]).First());

            File.WriteAllLines(indexPDFDocumentName, dictionaryFromArray.Select(z => z.Key + "=" + z.Value).ToArray());

            MessageBox.Show("Indexing Complete");
        }
    }
```

Comment: `the same file twice if found in multiple folders` what makes them the same? just name? what if their contents are different?

Comment: Probably build a `Dictionary<string, FileInfo>` with `Path.GetFileName` as a key, then dump the contents once enumeration is done?

Comment: Please check out my simple solution, I just posted below.

Answer (score 1):

Just making an assumption (skipping other files with the same name)

```
var files = new DirectoryInfo(@"d:\temp")
            .EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
            .Select(x => x.First().FullName)
            .ToArray();
```

Comment: Yes, what I want is to skip files with the same name. Your code also gives me files with the same name. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following simple LINQ solution:

```
//Assuming you get a list of filepaths as input.
List<string> filePathList = new List<string>()
{
    @"myfile1 = C:\Folder1\myfile1.PDF",
    @"myfile2 = C:\Folder2\myfile2.PDF",
    @"myfile3 = C:\Folder3\myfile3.PDF",
    @"myfile1 = C:\Folder4\myfile1.PDF"
};

//Group the files based on filenames (i.e Substring after the last '\' in their path)
//and select the "First" path of each group and ignore duplicates.
var uniqueFilePaths = filePathList.GroupBy(x => x.Split("\\").Last())
    .Select(x => x.First())
    .ToList();

/*  Output:
 *  "myfile1 = C:\Folder1\myfile1.PDF",
 *  "myfile2 = C:\Folder2\myfile2.PDF",
 *  "myfile3 = C:\Folder3\myfile3.PDF",
 */
```

The idea is simple, you `groupBy` based on filename and keep the first (or last) of each group. I would also recommend you to have a look at a [similar question I answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50399789/find-files-from-a-folder-containing-a-series-of-files-that-are-versioned-based-o/50400987#50400987).